# How to set focus for email after inserting text using WordEditor?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on Outlook add in.
I have task pane with button. On button click I inserted some text into email:

```
 var wordDocument = Application.ActiveInspector().WordEditor as Document;
 wordDocument.Application.Selection.TypeText("Some text");
```

After that email lost focus. How can I return focus back?

Comment: Are you wanting to return the text or return focus?

Comment: I want return focus to email